# video view and other view overlap issue

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a `VideoView` playing video at the center of the screen.After sometime, a msg view will pop up.

The position for this msg view is: part of the view is inside the `VideoView` area (which means this part actually is overlapped with the `VideoView`) while the other part is outside range of the `VideoView` area.

My problem is I found out that when the msg view pops up, the part which is outside the `VideoView` area will be shown immediately, however the other part, i.e.the part that is  overlapped with the `VideoView` is shown around 1 sec later.

I have no idea why it is so and how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Video view is quite special -  it is surface view, and basically  it is a black hole in your interface -  pixels are renderend by some other  application ( camera )  bypassing  you view hierarchy completely.  It is possible to put overlaz over it,   but it takes a big amount of synchronisation of your layout events / calls  with  video camera software.  This leads to delay for your pixel refresh.